# What is the easiest way to push an element to the beginning of the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I can't think of a one line way to do this.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 447, accepted):

What about using the [`unshift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-unshift) method?

> `ary.unshift(obj, ...) → ary`
> Prepends objects to the front of self, moving other elements upwards.

And in use:

```
a = [ 0, 1, 2]
a.unshift('x')
# => ["x", 0, 1, 2]
a.inspect
# => "["x", 0, 1, 2]"
```

Comment: That's the one I was looking for, forgot the name.

Comment: @Ed: That's why you bookmark http://www.ruby-doc.org/. `shift` and `unshift` operate on the beginning of an array, `push` and `pop` on the end.

Comment: I looked, just didn't see them in a quick scan.

Comment: @Ed: The method list at the top of the page could be better formatted, it is very difficult to visually scan as it is. I found it because I knew the method name I was looking for :)

Comment: If you are having trouble remembering between `shift` and `unshift` as to which adds to the array and which removes from the array, drop an 'f' from the names mentally and you get an all-too-clear picture as to the direction. (And then you have to remember that these methods don't work on the "end" of the array. ;)

Comment: @Phrogz The best mnemonic technique I've heard in years! :-)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that unshift is a lot slower than push. I believe push is O(1) while unshift is O(n) - correct me if I'm wrong. Definitely don't use unshift many times on large arrays. Shift and pop on the other hand appear to have the same time complexity.

Comment: @the_minted running a 1/10/100 million push vs. unshift benchmark shows that `array.push` is about 5%-15% faster than `array.unshift`. The more item the array contained the less faster #push worked.

Comment: @Phrogz I am still using that mnemonic to this day, and feeling weird passing it on to other people.

Comment: @Phrogz Very nice mnemonic! I feel the principle of least expectation being violated here however: less surprising names for these methods would be `puke` and `unpuke`, as the activity happens in the front part of the array.

Comment: I like the (un)shi(f)t mnemonic. The way I've always remembered is from bash/shell scripting where `shift` renumbers args lower, dropping the smallest numbered ones. `prepend` mentioned below since Ruby 2.5 is even easier to remember.

Answer (score 59):

You can use `insert`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.insert(0,'x')
=> ['x',1,2,3]
```

Where the first argument is the index to insert at and the second is the value.

Answer (score 26):

```
array = ["foo"]
array.unshift "bar"
array
=> ["bar", "foo"]
```

be warned, it's destructive!

Answer (score 26):

Since Ruby 2.5.0, Array ships with the `prepend`  method (which is just an alias for the `unshift` method).

Comment: This also works with ruby 2.4.4p296, so maybe just with ruby 2.4?

Answer (score 18):

You can also use [array concatenation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```
a = [2, 3]
[1] + a
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

This creates a new array and doesn't modify the original.

Comment: Seems like the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `methodsolver` to find Ruby functions.

Here is a small script,

```
require 'methodsolver'

solve { a = [1,2,3]; a.____(0) == [0,1,2,3] }
```

Running this prints

```
Found 1 methods
- Array#unshift
```

You can install methodsolver using

```
gem install methodsolver
```

Comment: Cool, didn't think this would be possible to write LOL

Comment: `irb> require 'methodsolver'` causes `LoadError: cannot load such file -- method_source` from ... from `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/methodsolver-0.0.4/lib/methodsolver.rb:2`.  Ruby 1.9.3p484, irb 0.9.6, Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Try using `pry` instead of `irb`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `prepend` and `delete`, which are both idiomatic and intention revealing:

```rb
array.delete(value)  # Remove the value from the array  
array.prepend(value) # Add the value to the beginning of the array
```

Or in a single line:

```rb
array.prepend(array.delete(value))
```